# Remove underscore and number at the end of string

Tags: r, regex, string, data-cleaning

I am working with a dataset that has column with some underscores. There is a patter to it but they are different patterns, as shown below

```
  ID     Col1
  1029   ap_analog
  2334   critical_1_mm_1
  2334   transpose_2_mm_2
  9877   public_1_yes_0_no_1
  9877   public_1_yes_0_no_2
  1333   Lateral_mm
  1333   Lateral_mm_1
  1333   Lateral_mm_2
  1333   Lateral_mm_3
  1333   ap_mm_axial
  1333   ap_mm_axial_1
  1333   ap_mm_axial_2
  1333   ap_mm_axial_3
  9876   central_star_six_mm
  9876   central_star_six_mm_1
  9876   central_star_six_mm_2
  9876   central_star_six_mm_3
```

I just like to separate the numbers from the string with a final dataset like this

```
  ID     Col1                     Index
  1029   ap_analog                0
  2334   critical_1_mm            1
  2334   transpose_2_mm           2
  9877   public_1_yes_0_no        1
  9877   public_1_yes_0_no        2
  1333   Lateral_mm               0
  1333   Lateral_mm               1
  1333   Lateral_mm               2  
  1333   Lateral_mm               3
  1333   ap_mm_axial              0
  1333   ap_mm_axial              1
  1333   ap_mm_axial              2
  1333   ap_mm_axial              3
  9876   central_star_six_mm      0
  9876   central_star_six_mm      1
  9876   central_star_six_mm      2
  9876   central_star_six_mm      3
```

Right now I am doing this very inefficiently. Something like this

```
df1$index <- df1$Col1

for(i in 1:3) {
  df1$index <-  regmatches(df1$index,gregexpr("(?<=_).*",df1$index,perl=TRUE))
}

df1$index[ which(df1$index == "character(0)")] <- 0
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve on this.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `dplyr` and `stringr` :

We can extract the `Index` value which is the number at the end of `Col1`, replace the `NA` values with 0. We can remove the last digit from `Col1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Index = str_extract(Col1, '\\d+$'), 
         Index = replace(Index, is.na(Index), 0), 
         Col1 = sub('_\\d+$', '', Col1))

#    ID                Col1 Index
#1  1029           ap_analog     0
#2  2334       critical_1_mm     1
#3  2334      transpose_2_mm     2
#4  9877   public_1_yes_0_no     1
#5  9877   public_1_yes_0_no     2
#6  1333          Lateral_mm     0
#7  1333          Lateral_mm     1
#8  1333          Lateral_mm     2
#9  1333          Lateral_mm     3
#10 1333         ap_mm_axial     0
#11 1333         ap_mm_axial     1
#12 1333         ap_mm_axial     2
#13 1333         ap_mm_axial     3
#14 9876 central_star_six_mm     0
#15 9876 central_star_six_mm     1
#16 9876 central_star_six_mm     2
#17 9876 central_star_six_mm     3
```

Comment: the solution above is not robust. It does not work if there are some numbers in between the string. If there are numbers in between the string it will remove that instead of the last number. I have updated my question with 4 new scenarios. `str_remove(Col1, Index)` is the suspect

Comment: @RiloDinga I don't know about all the possibilities that your data consist of. I can answer only based on the information that you share. The previous answer worked for your previous data and this new answer works for the new data. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: it was my mistake. I did not provide a good example. I will try this solution.